# Creating a temp table inside a PostgreSQL function creates conflicts between different function calls?

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

I want to use a temporary table (let's call it **temp_tbl**) created in a PostgreSQL function in order to SELECT into it just some rows and columns from a table (let's call it **tbl**) as follows:

One of the columns that both **temp_tbl** and **tbl** have is *order_date* of type DATE and the function also takes a *start_date* DATE argument. I want to SELECT in **temp_tbl** just the rows from **tbl** that have an *order_date* later than the function's *start_date*.

My question is: if this function gets called concurrently 2 or more times in the same session, won't the calls use the same instance of the temporary table **temp_tbl** ?

More specifically, when using psycopg2 in the backend of a webserver, different clients of the webserver might require calling our function at the same time. Will this generate a conflict over the **temp_tbl** temporary table declared inside the function?

**EDIT: my actual context**
I'm building (for education purposes) an online shop. I have 3 tables for 3 kinds of products that all use a common sequence for their ids. I have another table for orders that includes a column which is an array of product ids and a column which is an array of quantities (associated with the product ids of the ordered products). 
I want to return a table of common product details (columns common to all 3 tables like id, name, price etc) and their associated number of sales.

My current method is to concatenate all the arrays of ids and quantities from all order entries, then create a temporary table out of the 2 arrays and sum the number of orders for each product id so I have a table with one entry for each ordered product.
Then, I create 3 temporary tables in order to join each product table with the temporary product orders figures table and SELECT only the columns that are common to all 3 tables.
Finally, I UNION the 3 temporary tables.

This is kind of complicated for me so I think that maybe there were better design decisions I could have made ?

Comment: Why do you think you need a temp table - most of the time they are not needed to begin with. But they are "private" to the connection, so if the function is called from two different connections that will work

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Temporary tables are "seen" by all queries inside of the session it was created, so if your concern is about conflict with other sessions you don't have anything worry about. But, if the function creates the temporary table you might get an exception when the function is called for the first time in the same session, since it already exists. Happy new year!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you very much! I believe this answers my question. I am not really sure that I need temp tables. My use case is a bit messier, but I tried to boil the question down to my current obstacle. I added the whole context in the post because it didn't fit in this comment.

Comment: "... a column which is an array of product ids and a column which is an array of quantities ..." -- You should fix this and go with a regular normalized approach with a table linking items to orders.

Comment: @JimJones Thank you very much for your answer and happy new year! Related to the exception: I make sure to drop the table if it exists before I create it (is this what you mean?). And related to the sessions: I am also worried because I don't know how psycopg2 works as I intend to use it with Flask. Will it create a new session for each call to the stored function even if I don't explicitly create a new session from the Flask code? (I've never worked with psycopg2 before)

Comment: @AlexM. as a_horse_with_no_name said, temporary tables are rarely the best option. Normally you can solve it with other more sophisticated mechanisms, like a common table expression. This way you have nothing to worry about and your code is less vulnerable. Can you edit your question share the content of this function? Perhaps I could help ..

Comment: @stickybit If I understand correctly, I thought about this when I created the table: having an entry in the Orders table for each item in each order placed by each client, but I thought it felt a bit unnatural and I chose to design an order entry to encapsulate the whole shopping cart.

Comment: No, you have just one row in the orders table per order. Then you have another table that links the order to its items. That's the most "natural" way to model that in a relational database.